# swift ui Particles are pulled in from -45, 45, -135, and 135 degrees

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hello I have a button that shoots out particles. I also have a button that pulls in particles. The button that pushes particles out works great. The button that pulls in particles also works but for some reason particles are only pulled in from the corners (-45, 45, -135, and 135 degrees), I want the particles to be pulled in from all around not only the corners. Id appreciate some help. Thanks.

```
struct AllVideoView: View {
    @State private var isLiked: [Bool] = [false, false]
    var body: some View {
    
            VStack(spacing: 40){
                CustomButton(systemImage: "hand.thumbsup.fill", status: isLiked[0], activeTint: .green, inActiveTint: .gray) {
                    isLiked[0].toggle()
                    if isLiked[1] {
                        isLiked[1] = false
                    }
                }
                
                CustomButton(systemImage: "hand.thumbsdown.fill", status: isLiked[1], activeTint: .pink, inActiveTint: .gray) {
                    isLiked[1].toggle()
                    if isLiked[0] {
                        isLiked[0] = false
                    }
                }
            
        }
    }
    @ViewBuilder
    func CustomButton(systemImage: String, status: Bool, activeTint: Color, inActiveTint: Color, onTap: @escaping () -> ()) -> some View {
        Button(action: onTap) {
            Image(systemName: systemImage)
                .font(.title2)
                .particleEffect360(
                    systemImage: systemImage,
                    font: .body,
                    status: status,
                    activeTint: activeTint,
                    inActiveTint: inActiveTint,
                    direction: systemImage == "hand.thumbsup.fill" ? true : false
                )
                .foregroundColor(status ? activeTint : inActiveTint)
                .padding(18)
                .background {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(status ? activeTint.opacity(0.6) : Color.blue.opacity(0.6))
                }
            
        }
    }
}

struct Particle: Identifiable {//these particles are pushed from origin so start at 0,0
    var id: UUID = .init()
    var randomX: CGFloat = 0
    var randomY: CGFloat = 0
    var scale: CGFloat = 1
    var opacity: CGFloat = 1
    mutating func reset() {
        randomX = 0
        randomY = 0
        scale = 1
        opacity = 1
    }
}
struct Negative_Particle360: Identifiable {//these particles are pulled in so start them far from origin
    var id: UUID = .init()
    var randomX: CGFloat = Bool.random() ? CGFloat.random(in: -100...(-80)) : CGFloat.random(in: 80...100)
    var randomY: CGFloat = Bool.random() ? CGFloat.random(in: -100...(-80)) : CGFloat.random(in: 80...100)
    var scale: CGFloat = 1
    var opacity: CGFloat = 1

    mutating func reset() {
        if Bool.random() {
            randomX = CGFloat.random(in: -100...(-80))
        } else {
            randomX = CGFloat.random(in: 80...100)
        }
        if Bool.random() {
            randomY = CGFloat.random(in: -100...(-80))
        } else {
            randomY = CGFloat.random(in: 80...100)
        }
        scale = 1
        opacity = 1
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func particleEffect360(systemImage: String, font: Font, status: Bool, activeTint: Color, inActiveTint: Color, direction: Bool) -> some View {
        self
            .modifier(
                ParticleModifier360(systemImage: systemImage, font: font, status: status, activeTint: activeTint, inActiveTint: inActiveTint, direction: direction)
            )
        
    }
}

fileprivate struct ParticleModifier360: ViewModifier {
    var systemImage: String
    var font: Font
    var status: Bool
    var activeTint: Color
    var inActiveTint: Color
    var direction: Bool
    @State private var particles: [Particle] = []
    @State private var negative_particles: [Negative_Particle360] = []
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                ZStack {
                    if direction {
                        ForEach(particles) { particle in
                            Image(systemName: systemImage)
                                .font(font)
                                .foregroundColor(status ? activeTint : inActiveTint)
                                .scaleEffect(particle.scale)
                                .offset(x: particle.randomX, y: particle.randomY)
                                .opacity(particle.opacity)
                                .opacity(status ? 1 : 0)
                                .animation(.none, value: status)
                        }
                    } else {
                        ForEach(negative_particles) { particle in
                            Image(systemName: systemImage)
                                .font(font)
                                .foregroundColor(status ? activeTint : inActiveTint)
                                .scaleEffect(particle.scale)
                                .offset(x: particle.randomX, y: particle.randomY)
                                .opacity(particle.opacity)
                                .opacity(status ? 1 : 0)
                                .animation(.none, value: status)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    if direction {
                        if particles.isEmpty {
                            for _ in 1...15 {
                                let particle = Particle()
                                particles.append(particle)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if negative_particles.isEmpty {
                            for _ in 1...15 {
                                let particle = Negative_Particle360()
                                negative_particles.append(particle)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: status) { newValue in
                    if !newValue {
                        if direction {
                            for index in particles.indices {
                                particles[index].reset()
                            }
                        } else {
                            for index in negative_particles.indices {
                                negative_particles[index].reset()
                            }
                        }
                    } else {

                        if direction {.  //pushing particles out
                            for index in particles.indices {
                                let total: CGFloat = CGFloat(particles.count)
                                let progress: CGFloat = CGFloat(index) / total
                                
                                let angle: CGFloat = progress * 2 * .pi
                                
                                let radius: CGFloat = 75
                                let centerX: CGFloat = 0
                                let centerY: CGFloat = 0
                                
                                let randomX: CGFloat = radius * cos(angle) + centerX
                                let randomY: CGFloat = radius * sin(angle) + centerY
                                let randomScale: CGFloat = .random(in: 0.35...1)
                                
                                withAnimation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 0.7, blendDuration: 0.7)) {
                                    let extraRandomX: CGFloat = .random(in: -10...10)
                                    let extraRandomY: CGFloat = .random(in: 0...40)
                                    
                                    particles[index].randomX = randomX + extraRandomX
                                    particles[index].randomY = randomY + extraRandomY
                                }
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                                    particles[index].scale = randomScale
                                }
                                withAnimation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 0.7, blendDuration: 0.7)
                                    .delay(0.25 + (Double(index) * 0.005))) {
                                        particles[index].scale = 0.001
                                }
                            }
                        } else {//pulling particles in logic
                            for index in negative_particles.indices {
                                let randomScale: CGFloat = .random(in: 0.8...1)
                                
                                withAnimation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 0.7, blendDuration: 0.7)) {
                                    let extraRandomX: CGFloat = .random(in: -5...5)
                                    let extraRandomY: CGFloat = .random(in: -5...5)
                                    
                                    negative_particles[index].randomX = extraRandomX
                                    negative_particles[index].randomY = extraRandomY
                                }
                                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3)) {
                                    negative_particles[index].scale = randomScale
                                }
                                withAnimation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.6, dampingFraction: 0.7, blendDuration: 0.7)
                                    .delay(0.25 + (Double(index) * 0.005))) {
                                        negative_particles[index].scale = 0.001
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because your struct `Negative_Particle360` is only operating with offsets in the range 80...100 (positive and negative).

Try changing the range to be -100...100 instead.

*EDIT* Following up from your comment, you could also include a check that the combined offset is reasonably significant.

```swift
struct Negative_Particle360: Identifiable {//these particles are pulled in so start them far from origin
    let id = UUID()
    var randomX = CGFloat.zero
    var randomY = CGFloat.zero
    var scale = CGFloat(1)
    var opacity = CGFloat(1)

    init() {
        reset()
    }

    mutating func reset() {
        repeat {
            randomX = CGFloat.random(in: -100...100)
            randomY = CGFloat.random(in: -100...100)
        } while ((randomX * randomX) + (randomY * randomY)).squareRoot() < 75
        scale = 1
        opacity = 1
    }
}
```

*EDIT2* You were asking how to make the animation smoother - try this:

```swift
for index in negative_particles.indices {
    let randomScale: CGFloat = .random(in: 0.8...1)
    let targetX: CGFloat = .random(in: -5...5)
    let targetY: CGFloat = .random(in: -5...5)
    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5)) {
        negative_particles[index].randomX = targetX
        negative_particles[index].randomY = targetY
        negative_particles[index].scale = randomScale
    }
    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 0.5).delay(0.2)) {
            negative_particles[index].scale = 0.001
    }
}
```

I also changed the threshold in the other part of the answer to 75 (and changed the while loop to repeat...while, which is a bit simpler).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve the issue a little bit. I don't think that's the issue tho a range range 80...100 (positive and negative) only makes the particles start farther away from the origin. Making it -100...100 means a particle can start very close to the origin and wouldn't make it seem like its being dragged in.

Comment: OK, so you could also include a check that the combined offset is reasonably significant. Answer updated.

Comment: Looks better! Although it is not as smooth as the push It does the trick. If you know how to make it look more like the particle push but in reverse Id appreciate the help.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I think you just need to try out different animation parameters to make it seem smoother. This is the section of code which you have commented with ```//pulling particles in logic```. Giving the animations more duration might help.

Comment: Answer updated once more with a suggested animation change.

Comment: Thanks looks better since you're such a ui expert maybe you would help with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005183/time-slider-does-not-move-well-swift-ui