# Time Slider does not move well Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, youtube

I'm making a feature to seek any time period in a YouTube video. All you have to do is hold down anywhere on the screen then drag right or left.

The way the slider moves is very buggy and quick; I tried messing with the logic but I don't know how to make it smooth. To test this code you can just copy everything in (it's a lot) but ignore everything except for the `onChange` block in the top view. That contains all the logic for moving the slider.

How can I smooth it out? I know I can add an animation and a duration to it but I think it's better if the slider is more responsive and smooth on its own. I just have to fix the logic in the `onChange`.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import UIKit


enum DragState: Equatable {
    case inactive
    case pressing
    case dragging(translation: CGSize)

    var translation: CGSize {
        switch self {
        case .inactive, .pressing:
            return .zero
        case .dragging(let translation):
            return translation
        }
    }
    var isDragging: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .dragging:
            return true
        case .pressing, .inactive:
            return false
        }
    }
    var isPressing: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .inactive:
            return false
        case .pressing, .dragging:
            return true
        }
    }
}

struct SingleVideoView: View {
    let link: String
    @State private var isVideoPlaying = false
    @State private var click = false
    @State private var currentTime = 5.0
    @State private var totalLength = 46.0
    @GestureState private var dragState = DragState.inactive
    @State private var fillCircles = 0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            
            SmartReelView(link: link, isPlaying: $isVideoPlaying, click: $click, totalLength: $totalLength, currentTime: $currentTime)

            Button("", action: {}).disabled(true)
            
            Color.gray.opacity(0.001)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isVideoPlaying.toggle()
                }
                .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.01)
                    .sequenced(before: DragGesture().onEnded({ _ in
                        isVideoPlaying = true
                    }))
                    .updating(self.$dragState, body: { (value, dstate, _) in
                        switch value {
                        case .first:
                            dstate = .pressing
                        case .second(true, let drag):
                            dstate = .dragging(translation: drag?.translation ?? .zero)
                        default:
                            break
                        }
                    })
                )
            if (dragState.isPressing || dragState.isDragging) && totalLength != 0.0 {
                ZStack(alignment: .center){
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).fill(.ultraThinMaterial)
                    HStack {
                        Text("0:00").foregroundColor(.white).font(.subheadline)
                        Spacer()
                        ZStack(alignment: .leading){
                            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 1) {
                                ForEach(0..<50, id: \.self) { _ in
                                    Circle().frame(width: 4, height: 4)
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                }
                            }
                            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 1) {
                                ForEach(0..<fillCircles, id: \.self) { _ in
                                    Circle().frame(width: 4, height: 4)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                            }
                            HStack {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2){
                                    Text(formatTime(seconds: currentTime)).foregroundColor(.white).font(.caption).offset(x: -12)
                                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 1, height: 25)
                                    Spacer()
                                }.offset(x: CGFloat(fillCircles * 5)).padding(.top, 6)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Text(formatTime(seconds: totalLength)).foregroundColor(.white).font(.subheadline)
                    }.padding(.horizontal, 10)
                }.padding(.horizontal).frame(height: 80).offset(y: -widthOrHeight(width: false) * 0.2)
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onDisappear {
            isVideoPlaying = false
            click = false
        }
        .onAppear {
            isVideoPlaying = true
        }
        .onChange(of: dragState) { _ in
            if (dragState.isPressing || dragState.isDragging) && totalLength != 0.0 {
                isVideoPlaying = false
                let translation = dragState.translation.width
                if translation > 5 {
                    let timeLeft = totalLength - currentTime
                    let changeRatio = ((translation / 300) > 1) ? 1 : translation / 300
                    let timeToAdd = changeRatio * timeLeft
                    currentTime += timeToAdd
                } else if translation < -5 {
                    let changeRatio = ((abs(translation) / 300) > 1) ? 1 : abs(translation) / 300
                    let timeToSubtract = changeRatio * currentTime
                    currentTime -= timeToSubtract
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: currentTime) { _ in
            fillCircles = Int((currentTime / totalLength) * 50)
        }
    }
    func formatTime(seconds: Double) -> String {
        let minutes = Int(seconds) / 60
        let remainingSeconds = Int(seconds) % 60

        if minutes < 1 {
            return String(format: "0:%02d", remainingSeconds)
        } else {
            return String(format: "%d:%02d", minutes, remainingSeconds)
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SingleVideoView(link: "-q6-DxWZnlQ")
    }
}

struct SmartReelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool
    @Binding var click: Bool
    @Binding var totalLength: Double
    @Binding var currentTime: Double
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator

        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()

        userContentController.add(context.coordinator, name: "toggleMessageHandler")
        
        webView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController

        loadInitialContent(in: webView)
        
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let jsString = """
                isPlaying = \((isPlaying || click) ? "true" : "false");
                watchPlayingState();
                seekToTime(\(currentTime));
            """
        uiView.evaluateJavaScript(jsString, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: SmartReelView

        init(_ parent: SmartReelView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
            if let messageDict = message.body as? [String: Any], let duration = messageDict["duration"] as? Double {
                self.parent.click = true
                self.parent.totalLength = duration
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false) { _ in
                    self.parent.click = false
                }
            }
            if let messageDict = message.body as? [String: Any], let currentTime = messageDict["currentTime"] as? Double {
                self.parent.currentTime = currentTime
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loadInitialContent(in webView: WKWebView) {
        let embedHTML = """
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                background-color: black;
            }
            .iframe-container iframe {
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="iframe-container">
            <div id="player"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            var isPlaying = true;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: '\(link)',
                    playerVars: { 'playsinline': 1, 'controls': 0},
                    events: {
                        'onReady': function(event) {
                            if (window.webkit && window.webkit.messageHandlers && window.webkit.messageHandlers.toggleMessageHandler) {
                                window.webkit.messageHandlers.toggleMessageHandler.postMessage({
                                    "message": "click now",
                                    "duration": player.getDuration()
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        'onStateChange': function(event) {
                            if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                                player.seekTo(0);
                                player.playVideo();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            
            function watchPlayingState() {
                if (isPlaying) {
                    player.playVideo();
                } else {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
            }
        
            function sendCurrentTime() {
                if (player && window.webkit && window.webkit.messageHandlers && window.webkit.messageHandlers.toggleMessageHandler) {
                    const currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
                    window.webkit.messageHandlers.toggleMessageHandler.postMessage({
                        "currentTime": currentTime
                    });
                }
            }
            function seekToTime(seconds) {
                if (player && seconds > 0.0) {
                    player.seekTo(seconds);
                    timeToSeek = 0.0;
                }
            }

            setInterval(sendCurrentTime, 1000);
        
        </script>
        """
        
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason it is quick may be because the ```onChange``` callback is computing the fraction of video using a hard-coded value of 300. This probably needs to be the width of the scale on the display, trying 1000 certainly slows it down. If the true width is not known then a ```GeometryReader``` could be used to find it. And the reason it is buggy (sometimes moving in the wrong direction) is probably the logic related to the ```DragGesture```. I don't really understand the states it is using, but if it moves the wrong way then there's something wrong in the way it is handling the drag offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing `currentTime` incrementally when it should be moved relative to a reference point that begins with the start of the drag.

Introduce a new `@State var`:

```
@State private var startDragTime = 0.0
```

Then set `startDragTime` when `dragState` changes but you're not currently dragging.  Use `startDragTime` instead of `currentTime` in your calculations.  This way, the new `currentTime` will always be relative to the `startDragTime` and the distance you have dragged since the beginning.

I also replaced `300` with `speed` which can be tuned.

```
.onChange(of: dragState) { _ in
    let speed: CGFloat = 100
    if (!dragState.isDragging) {
        startDragTime = currentTime
    }
    if (dragState.isPressing || dragState.isDragging) && totalLength != 0.0 {
        isVideoPlaying = false
        let translation = dragState.translation.width
        if translation > 5 {
            let timeLeft = totalLength - startDragTime
            let changeRatio = ((translation / speed) > 1) ? 1 : (translation / speed)
            let timeToAdd = changeRatio * timeLeft
            currentTime = startDragTime + timeToAdd
        } else if translation < -5 {
            let changeRatio = ((abs(translation) / speed) > 1) ? 1 : (abs(translation) / speed)
            let timeToSubtract = changeRatio * startDragTime
            currentTime = startDragTime - timeToSubtract
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great thanks a lot. If you would take a sec to look at this question Id appreciate it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005364/swift-ui-putting-view-in-tab-and-rotating-it-messes-up-alignment