# Swift ui Putting view In tab and rotating it messes up alignment

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hello I want to make a tab view that scrolls vertically, to accomplish this I rotate the tab view 90 degrees and rotate the inner view neg 90 degrees to get everything straight. But in doing so it seems like the inner view gets distorted and widened. When I comment out all the tab view stuff and rotation and only display a singular SingleVideoView (passing in a link directly) then it looks just fine. There's something wrong with how the Tab View lays out the subviews. Taking out all .frame modifiers the SingleVideoView is smaller than it should be. Putting a frame modifier on the overall tabView makes the view the right size but also stretches it horizontally. How can I fix this.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AllVideoView: View {
    @State private var selected = ""
    @Namespace private var animation
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TabView(selection: $selected){
                ForEach(arr, id: \.self){ id in
                    SingleVideoView(link: id)
                        .tag(id)
                        .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                        .frame(height: widthOrHeight(width: false))
                }
            }
            .frame(width: widthOrHeight(width: false))
            .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .background(Color.black)
        }
    }
}
func widthOrHeight(width: Bool) -> CGFloat {
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    
    if width {
        return window?.screen.bounds.width ?? 0
    } else {
        return window?.screen.bounds.height ?? 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue I had to put a frame modifier on both the inside element and the tab view then offset the element into the frame of the screen. This stops the tabView from stretching the element as seen in the original code:

```
            GeometryReader { proxy in
            TabView {
                ForEach(arr, id: \.self){ id in
                    SingleVideoView(link: id)
                }
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
                .frame(
                    width: proxy.size.width,
                    height: proxy.size.height
                )
            }
            .frame(
                width: proxy.size.height,
                height: proxy.size.width
            )
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(90), anchor: .topLeading)
            .offset(x: proxy.size.width)
            .tabViewStyle(
                PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never)
            )
            .background(Color.black)
        }
```